# Selecting Unique/Distinct fields on DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

Hello all I have written a query that is suppose to pull the zip codes of two locations and their rates. 
However I only want one zip per shipper, but for some reason it is still returning multiple fields.

```
SELECT UNIQUE LEFT(T.ORIGPC,3) SHIP_ZIP,  LEFT(T.DESTPC,3) DEST_ZIP, BILL_NUMBER, T.ORIGCITY, T.ORIGPROV, 
T.DESTCITY, T.DESTPROV, A.RATE, T.DISTANCE
FROM TLORDER T, ACHARGE_TLORDER A
WHERE CREATED_TIME >= CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 1 MONTH
AND BILL_NUMBER <> '0'
AND DISTANCE <> '0'
AND RATE <> '0'
AND RATE NOT LIKE '-%'
AND DISTANCE NOT LIKE '-%'
AND ORIGPC <> ''
AND REQUESTED_CODE = 'FS_STD' 
AND A.DETAIL_LINE_ID = T.DETAIL_LINE_ID
AND DESTPC <> ''
AND BILL_NUMBER NOT LIKE 'Q%'
AND ACODE_ID = 'FS_STD'
AND RATE <= '2' 
ORDER BY LEFT(ORIGPC,3)
```

[image: Hidden Bill Number for obvious reasons]

expected result 
[image]

Comment: Can you include your expected output?

Comment: What does UNIQUE mean? (Each row are distinct here.)

Comment: Did you try `distinct` with `group by` clause?

Comment: i tried grouping and i received error 42803

Comment: Will you provide your group by statement?

Comment: SELECT distinct LEFT(T.ORIGPC,3) SHIP_ZIP,  LEFT(T.DESTPC,3) DEST_ZIP, BILL_NUMBER, T.ORIGCITY, T.ORIGPROV, 
T.DESTCITY, T.DESTPROV, A.RATE, T.DISTANCE
FROM TLORDER T, ACHARGE_TLORDER A
WHERE CREATED_TIME >= CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 1 MONTH
AND BILL_NUMBER <> '0'
AND DISTANCE <> '0'
AND RATE <> '0'
AND RATE NOT LIKE '-%'
AND DISTANCE NOT LIKE '-%'
AND ORIGPC <> ''
AND REQUESTED_CODE = 'FS_STD' 
AND A.DETAIL_LINE_ID = T.DETAIL_LINE_ID
AND DESTPC <> ''
AND BILL_NUMBER NOT LIKE 'Q%'
AND ACODE_ID = 'FS_STD'
AND RATE <= '2' group by left(origpc,3)
ORDER BY LEFT(ORIGPC,3)

Comment: group by `LEFT(T.ORIGPC,3) SHIP_ZIP, LEFT(T.DESTPC,3) DEST_ZIP, BILL_NUMBER, T.ORIGCITY, T.ORIGPROV, T.DESTCITY, T.DESTPROV, A.RATE, T.DISTANCE`

Comment: @SHAIKH running with both unique and distinct return same values

Answer (score 0):

Remove Bill_number, and Distance! 
As a result only unique zip codes populated 
thanks for your time guys